# Running 2 CherryPy instances on the same machine

Tags: cherrypy

I am running CherryPy as a webserver on a remote Linux machine. End users access a website over the internet which the CherryPy instance serves. So far, so good.

Now, I want to have a dev version of the site, running on the same machine but on a different port, so that I can develop and test without disturbing the prod website. I need to do development on the same machine because it contains a lot of data which would not be practical to move to a different machine.

The code for the dev instance is in a different directory, of course, so as I edit the dev code it does not trigger a reload for the prod instance or affect the prod instance in any way.

However, if I configure my dev instance to run on a different port than the prod instance and try to start up the dev instance, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/process/wspbus.py", line 197, in publish
    output.append(listener(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/_cpserver.py", line 151, in start
    ServerAdapter.start(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/process/servers.py", line 167, in start
    wait_for_free_port(*self.bind_addr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cherrypy/process/servers.py", line 410, in wait_for_free_port
    raise IOError("Port %r not free on %r" % (port, host))
IOError: Port 8080 not free on '127.0.0.1'
```

Neither the dev nor prod instance are running on port 8080. The prod instance is on SSL (443) and the dev instance I can put on an arbitrary port (let's suppose it's on 98765). I haven't specified 8080 anywhere in any config file. So I didn't expect there to be a port conflict, However, it appears that for one instance, CherryPy spawns 2 processes- I guess there is some sort of parent-child relationship- and one of the processes is somehow listening on `localhost:8080`. Because this happens for both instances I try to launch, the second one is unable to launch because there ends up being this conflict on 8080.

I have tried several things, such as turning off autoreloading and timeout monitoring, in the hopes that CherryPy would not launch the process associated with 8080, but no luck so far.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is there another process running on port 8080?

Comment: @sarah: Thanks for your help. According to netstat, there is nothing running on 8080 on the machine.

Comment: Actually, if I run nmap, it does say that something is running on 8080: 8080/tcp open  http-proxy

Comment: The process on 8080 is (as expected) the first, prod cherrypy instance (even though it's listening on ssl (443) ). If I kill the python process for the first instance, then nmap no longer shows the http-proxy listening on 8080.

Comment: OK, I found a workaround. It's a total hack, but I'll mention it just in case it's useful to someone else as desperate as I was. I downloaded CherryPy-3.2.2 again, put the code in a different dir than the original CherryPy installation, set my PYTHONPATH when running my dev code so that it hits this new CherryPy-3.2.2 installation, and changed line 25 of _cpserver.py to be 'socket_port=8081' instead of 'socket_port=8080'. Like I said, a total hack, but at least I can work on the dev site now!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, to fix add this to each cherrypy

```
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1',
                        'server.socket_port': 9023
                        })
```